# Android [ENTER]-key action of a multiline edittext in a dialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, newline

I've create a dialog with a multiline edittext-field. The problem is that the [ENTER]-key of the soft keyboard is closing the keyboard instead of creating a new line. With imeOptions, it's possible to configure a lot, but not a newline-command... How **can** I accomplish this?

Building for a Galaxy Tab 2 with Android 4.0.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that setting the **raw** inputtype of the EditText to multiline **is** working where the "normal" input type isn't.

```
final EditText remark = new EditText(MyClass.this);    
remark.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

This did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish this by creating a new TextWatcher. Register this textwatcher to your EditText and implement a breakline when receiveing the return key.

EDIT:

To handle an individual key press, implement onKeyDown() or onKeyUp() as appropriate. Usually, you should use onKeyUp() if you want to be sure that you receive only one event. If the user presses and holds the button, then onKeyDown() is called multiple times.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {

         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:

             /* This is a sample for handling the Enter button */

             return true


        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Source:

Android :

http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html

A list of the KeyEvents:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: As far as I can find a TextWatcher can only monitor the entered text and not functionkeys like the enter (return) button. Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: This indeed works for overriding the behaviour of the keyboard keys. Although I found a much simpeler solution.. Thanks in any case, it helped me a lot.